# How to add markdown math rendering in Mezzanine (Python)

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook, mathjax, mezzanine

I've started a Mezzanine blog/site to write my survey paper (to share with others or what not).

I've written the individual posts as ipython notebooks, and then used nbconvert to change it into markdown. I'm using page-down in my Mezzanine site (atkoh.pythonwhere.com).

The problem is: the math does not render. Is there some sort of plugin or tutorial?

For example, my code shows the following:

$\frac{1}{2}$

Disclaimer: I have almost no background in web development, and I know basic HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your website to include [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). If you want to use `$...$` in addition to `$$...$$`, you could additionally use [python-markdown-mathjax](https://github.com/mayoff/python-markdown-mathjax).

But if you have no background in web development, as you state, you may be better off converting your Markdown with [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) which has builtin options to use a range of different technologies for [math rendering when exporting to HTML](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#math-rendering-in-html) (depending on which browsers and what kind of math expressions you need to support). For example:

```
pandoc input.md -t html5 --standalone --mathjax -o output.html
```